# pdf button not working in DataTables

Tags: pdf, datatable, datatables, tabletools

I have used the datatables in my html page.
I have inserted a pdf button which will save the document/table in pdf format.This is a default feature in datatables.

However, the button is not working though it is displayed in the html page.

Below is my code :

**datatable.html**

```
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.7/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>-->

<body>
<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

</table>

<script>

    $(document).ready( function () {

  var data = [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant"
    ]
    ];

    $('#example').dataTable({
         "aaData": data,
         "dom" : 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
         "tableTools" : {
            "sSwfPath": "DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
         }
    });
} );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What to do ?

Comment: Do you have flash enabled for the page? This is a very common cause of tabletools not working. Also it is always a good idea to give sSwfPath an absolute path.

Comment: Is your Export button appearing in view. If so check the .swf file. The path of the file may be wrong

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this :
add following js and css in following sequence :

https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js
https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

    $(function () {

    var data = [
        [
            "Tiger Nixon",
            "System Architect"],
        [
            "Garrett Winters",
            "Accountant"]
    ];

     $('#example').dataTable( {
         "aaData": data,
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    } );


});
```